# How to move GCC in osx from xcode to /usr/bin

Tags: macos, gcc, terminal

I have the gcc compiler in "/Developer/usr/bin/gcc" but when i type in gcc into terminal it says can not be found, i assume this is because its not in the "/usr/bin" dir. So can i a) move gcc from the first dir to the second, or set some kind of shortcut pointing gcc to "/Developer/usr/bin/gcc"

Comment: It sounds like you've been messing woth the standard developer tools install - ideally you should re-install Xcode and get everything in its proper place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two choices:

1. Edit your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` (or equivalent system files) and add `/Developer/usr/bin/gcc` to `$PATH`: `export PATH="$PATH:/Developer/usr/bin/"`
2. Create a link (symlink in this example) in your `/usr/bin` directory pointing to the real file: `ln -s /Developer/usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/gcc`

**Note: in XCode 4.5 on MacOS 10.8 the path is now:** /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin

Comment: Id go with the `.bash_*` edits. less possibility of issues than with the symlink.

Comment: I can edit ~/.bash_profile , can you elaborate more on what i have to do please ? i dont want to screw up system files

Comment: @kizzie33 You'd need to either find where the `$PATH` variable is modified, or add the line `export PATH="$PATH:/Developer/usr/bin/"` (with quotes) to the end of the file. The ones in your home directory aren't system files (edited answer to clarify what I meant), so you wouldn't be breaking any other accounts if you made a mistake

Answer (score 8):

The tip thewoolleyman linked to worked for me! I have installed Xcode 4.3.3 via the App Store. I did not have to install Xcode "again", seems Apple solved that. What I had to do are the following easy steps:

1. Open Xcode
2. Go To Preferences > Downloads
3. Install the Command Line Tools

Thanks to Guy and his post https://stackoverflow.com/a/9377095/1451903

Answer (score 2):

Use `ln -s` to create a symlink in `/usr/bin`, or add `/Developer/usr/bin` to `$PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

You can, in theory, hardlink it to the proper place.

The official way to do this is to install the optional "command-line tools" with the XCode installer. This wastes several hundred megabytes as it installs a new copy of the same compiler.

I wrote a shell script once to compare the installation trees of the "XCode" installation and the "command-line" installation and hardlink together all the files that were identical. It worked perfectly but the next upgrade undid it.

Another alternative is to download the GCC source from their CVS (not much bigger than downloading the massive XCode installer), and build it into `usr/bin/` yourself. Then you have the latest and greatest (or your choice of many newer and better versions) to play with.

Answer (score 0):

If you have "installed" Xcode from the App Store, check out this thread:

[Mac OS X Lion Xcode problems using RVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6848035/mac-os-x-lion-xcode-problems-using-rvm)

Apparently, "installing" Xcode from the app store doesn't actually install it, you must manually run the installer (search for "Install Xcode" in spotlight).