# Mac OS X Lion Xcode problems using RVM

Tags: ruby, xcode, xcode4, rvm, osx-lion

I had Xcode 4.1 preview 5 working fine but decided to upgrade to the final xcode 4.1 thru the App store.  I uninstalled Xcode first...

```
sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools –mode=all
```

Then installed Xcode thru the app store and rebooted.

I also removed RVM completely but... now whenever I try and install a version of Ruby it fails.  In the error file i get this:

```
[2011-07-27 18:29:25]  ./configure --prefix="/Users/holden/.rvm/usr"  
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... config/install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... no
checking for gcc... /usr/bin/gcc-4.2
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/holden/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

There is no gcc-4.2 or any other gcc in the /usr/bin directory.

What's up with Xcode?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Apparently even after downloading and "installing" XCode from the Appstore and despite the long process after downloading where it appears to install it and the words "Installed" eventually become displayed next to it in the store.  You must still manually install it again within your applications folder before it will work.

Odd.

Comment: This. If you're not seeing `gcc-4.2` in your `/usr/bin` directory, Xcode isn't installed. The bit you download from the App Store is actually the installer (titled *Install Xcode*, IIRC). You'll have to run that (it's in `/Applications`) and *then* reboot.

Comment: Ironically, any other company's apps would get rejected for that kind of confusing crap.

Comment: You must install the installer!  I'm sure Stevie is forcing someone to jump onto their own sword for that one.

Answer (score 18):

Just bought a Mac,
what I had to do to make it work after installing Xcode and seeing that /usr/bin doesn't have gcc, was:
Enter Xcode preferences going over to the downloads tab and install Command Line Tools.
After setting up my developer account and downloading the tools I opened terminal and typed

```
rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang
```

and everything compiled and works.

Comment: thanks! I spent a lot of time trying another variants, and only your's helped.

Answer (score 2):

Note - after running "Install Xcode" I still only have "gcc" in /usr/bin, not gcc-4.2.  But still worked fine, /usr/bin/gcc was a symlink to /usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2

Comment: I did it with sym-linking to /usr/bin/gcc-4.2. The command is: sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.2

Answer (score 0):

Guy's answer above seems to fix the problem compiling Ruby in RVM with XCode 4.2 installed completely, and removed for me to install GCC from https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer .  This is preferable for users needing to have both RVM and XCode 4.2 installed.